# Select checkbox ng-if parent checkbox is slected, both parent & child is uncountable diff. array

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

Structure is

```
$scope.divisions = [
  { Description: 'test1', Id: 1 },
  { Description: 'test2', Id: 2 },
  { Description: 'test3', Id: 3 },
  { Description: 'test4', Id: 4 },
  { Description: 'test5', Id: 5 }
];

  $scope.subd = [
  { Description: 'sub1', Id: 7 },
  { Description: 'sub2', Id: 8 },
  { Description: 'sub3', Id: 9 }
];
```

If test1 is selected subd should display under that,subd can be selectable.

I wants to catch only id of division and subd.

check it on Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/hjb5HTITyJelqdjLN5h2?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

If you want the parent to be selected just only when one or more children are selected then you might consider disabling parent input and update it based upon selected children.

Also store them on a new variable `$scope.selected` as json.

```
<ul class="radio-check-group">
    <li ng-repeat="d in divisions">
      <input disabled type="checkbox" ng-model="d.selected" class="" id="{{'div' + d.Id}}" name="selectedDivisions[]" />
      <label for="div{{$index}}">{{d.Description}}</label>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="s in d.subd">
        {{$parent.$index}}
          <input type="checkbox" ng-change="updateParent(d)" ng-model="s.selected" class="" id="{{'div' + d.Id}}" name="selectedsubd[]" />
          <label for="div{{$index}}">{{s.Description}}</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And controller function:

```
function initializeDivisionSubd() {
    angular.forEach($scope.divisions, d => {
        d.subd = angular.copy($scope.subd);
    })
};

$scope.selected = [];

initializeDivisionSubd();

$scope.updateParent = (parent) => {
    parent.selected = !!parent.subd.find(s => s.selected);
    $scope.selected = angular.toJson($scope.divisions.filter(d => d.selected).map(d => {
      return {
        Id: d.Id,
        subd: d.subd.filter(sd => sd.selected).map(sd => {
          return {
            Id: sd.Id
          }
        })
      }
    }));
```

Here's the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uv5o4w7h/9/)

Comment: hello, @korte,                                                                                                           If none of the child is selected ,parent should be unselected, and it's not only for test1, If any of the division is selected it should show list of subd.   And where you are storing it's respective json.

Comment: ya! , that's fine but can you implement it for all test1,test2... and storing as json as shown in my question's plunker

Comment: Check again please

Comment: I've also added the selected ones

Comment: but subd's selected id  is not getting added to it's respective division in json

Comment: What exactly do you need ?

Comment: as you can see in json it's only printing parent(division ID), child(subd ID) is not getting selected.

Comment: greate!! just last question, why slash( \ ) is getting printed in json [{\"Id\":1,\"subd\":[{\"Id\":7}]}]

Comment: because it's json. If you want it not to be json, just remove `angular.toJson()` wrapper.

Comment: hi, korte can you please do it same thing using multiple selectable dropdown . I have done it but selected value is not getting pushed to its respective parent.

Comment: hello @korte ,can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654233/nested-dropdown-ng-options-inside-ng-repeat-in-angularjs                               unable to catch parent details