# Nested Dropdown- ng-options inside ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, dropdown, ng-options

I wants to catch parent name and id on child selection.

Output should be:

```
$scope.selected = [{"name": "Request1", "id":1,
                    "status":[{"name":"status1","isSelected":true},
                              {"name":"status2","isSelected":false}]
                   }]
```

Able to get selected child but respective parent not getting.

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('demo', []);


app.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.requests=[{"name": "Request1", "id":1}, 
                     {"name": "Request2", "id":2},{"name": "Request3", "id":3}
                    ];
    $scope.statusList =[{ "name": "status1", "isSelected": true },
                        { "name": "status2", "isSelected": false }
                        ]
      function initializeRequestStatus() {
        angular.forEach($scope.requests, request => {
          request.statusList = angular.copy($scope.statusList);
        })
      };

      initializeRequestStatus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='demo'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<div class="container" ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        
        <ul ng-repeat="request in requests">
            {{request.name}}
            <li>
                <select class="form-control" ng-options="status as status.name for status in request.statusList"  ng-model="request.selectedStatus" multiple></select>
            </li>
        </ul>
       
        <ul>
          <li  ng-repeat="request in requests">{{request.selectedStatus}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can utilize the $index for getting the parent name and id.

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('demo', []);


app.controller('myController', function($scope){
    var result = [];
    $scope.requests=[{"name": "Request1", "id":1}, 
                     {"name": "Request2", "id":2},{"name": "Request3", "id":3}
                    ];
    $scope.statusList =[{ "name": "status1", "isSelected": true },
                        { "name": "status2", "isSelected": false }
                        ];
    
    $scope.getParent = function(index, selectedState){
      result = [];
      var req = {
        "name": $scope.requests[index].name, 
        "id": $scope.requests[index].id, 
        "status": selectedState
      }
      result.push(req);
      console.log("result",result);
      return angular.toJson(result);
    };
    
    function initializeRequestStatus() {
        angular.forEach($scope.requests, request => {
          request.statusList = angular.copy($scope.statusList);
        })
      };

      initializeRequestStatus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='demo'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<div class="container" ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        
        <ul ng-repeat="request in requests">
            {{request.name}}
            <li>
                <select class="form-control" ng-click="getParent($index, request.selectedStatus)" ng-options="status as status.name for status in request.statusList"  ng-model="request.selectedStatus" multiple></select>
            </li>
        </ul>
       
        <ul>
          <li  ng-repeat="request in requests">{{request.selectedStatus}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to push parent details with their respective selected child to get json as output i have given in question

Comment: @RaaZuSaH  the result json is which parent with which selected child.
Please see my flunker I returned the outpur in json.
http://plnkr.co/edit/9ZKjrDC0tjlLcfpRGy9w?p=preview

Comment: i have already mention in the question output should be in json with parent and child details. parent(requests) and child(statusList)

Comment: My current json is this.
[{"name":"Request2","id":2,"status":[{"name":"status1","isSelected":true}]}]

Comment: And if you want your output as in thenquestion then pass  $scope.statusList to status key .

Comment: yes, you are right but whenever we select next dropdown it replacing the previous dropdown values.   i have edited you plunker check it out http://plnkr.co/edit/5pd1cNrQ7AtZ5ops7pVR?p=preview

Comment: I hope you will happy with my code 
http://plnkr.co/edit/QlUjIe3IDy9eG7rF98Pn?p=preview

Comment: great! but one issue is there whenever we deselect all child element, parent id and name is not getting removed from json

Comment: Hey I got some time from office and then make some contribution for this post.
Here Dynamica selection of drop-down by ng-selected.
Please find my new plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/TwZm3c0aaH8197bmMYmz?p=preview

Comment: can you please check inside status only statusList name is getting selected, i need both status: [{ "name": "status1", "isSelected": true }]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17604875)

Comment: now that this isn't a link only answer (Maybe do this yourself next time?) This requires some form of explanation oir least what you have changed how this is relevant to the OP, etc.

Comment: @Liam Thanks for your advice. I will take care these types of things in future.